# GTK: cancel timeout

Tags: gtk, glib

GTK allows you to set a timeout with `g_timeout_add`.  Just like `g_signal_connect`, the `g_timeout_add` function returns an id representing the timeout.  So, is there a way to *cancel* a timeout using the id?  Looking through the [documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.31/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html), I don't see any way to cancel a timeout event, but I would assume there must be some way, otherwise what is the point of the `id` value returned by `g_timeout_add`?

So, is there any way to cancel a timeout event, or is this just something that needs to be handled manually by setting a "cancellation flag" which can be checked within the user-provided timeout handler function?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two ways to remove a callback registered through [g_timeout_add()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add):

- Have the callback function return `FALSE`,
- Call [g_source_remove()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-remove) with the identifier returned by `g_timeout_add()`.

Comment: is there anyway where I can cancel the call back before the first call. Ex: I schedule it after 10 secs and I decide to cancel it after 5 secs (its not yet called). After the first call back you will get identifier using which you can cancel but is it possible to cancel before that?

Comment: @Sagar, yes, with `g_source_remove()`. It takes the identifier returned by `g_timeout_add()`, so you don't have to wait for the callback to be invoked.

Comment: Oh i got it now. schedule func using g_timeout_add(), using the ret value from g_timeout_add(), you can cancel the call back invocation. Is my understanding is right?

Comment: For future googling: a message such as `GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID <id> was not found when attempting to remove it` may indicate that `g_source_remove()` was called to remove a timeout handler that was not propely configured.